# A better way of storing the user permissions in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I want to store user permissions somewhere else and not in localstorage since its not secure.
I tried storing it on global state dispatching a custom actions using a custom saga when USER_LOGIN action is dispatched upon login but it didnt work. This is my code:

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { showNotification } from 'react-admin';

export default function* updatePermissions() {
  yield takeEvery('RA/USER_LOGIN //(also tried only USER_LOGIN)', function*() {
    yield put(showNotification('test test '));
  });
}
```

How can i store something from the response i get on login function(authProvider.js) to global state?
And what do you recommend another way of storing the user permissions in React-admin?